# Edit HTTP header prior to forwarding

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, network-programming, arp

I want to create a python programme that edits the headers of a of HTTP message before forwarding it in a Man in the Middle attack.

I allowed port forwarding in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

I am ARP spoofing with `arpspoof`

Could I edit the headers before retransmitting them in python or do I need to dabble with C built sockets below the application layer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use sockets in python?

https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/socket-example.html

Or just a python HTTP server and you make it run as a proxy. You read the HTTP request, modify the headers as necessary and resend it.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.server.html